# Regular expression in ruby 2.1.5

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract `alpha-beta` from:

```
text = "alpha-beta-1.0.txt"
```

to get:

```
output = "alpha-beta"
```

Can somebody here help me with a regex?

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/2qsM4tdr2Z

Comment: `output = text[/alpha-beta/]` is the solution.

Comment: There's no point to extracting "alpha-beta" if you know that substring is present. Do you want to determine if it is present, or are "alpha" and "beta" stand-ins for words generally? For this question to make sense you need to define the pattern you wish to apply. You can't do that with an example. You could say, for example, that you want to extract the first string that contains two words, comprised of lowercase letters, that are separated by a hyphen. That may not be what you want but it should give you an idea of what's needed.

Answer (score 3):

> If you have a computer programming problem, and you think, "I'll use a
>   regex!", now you have two problems.

Here it is without a regex:

```
strings = [
  "alpha-beta-1.0.txt",
  "alpha-beta-theta-2.0.txt",
  "alpha-3.0.text",
]

strings.each do |string|
  output = string.rpartition('-')[0]
  puts output
end

--output:--
alpha-beta
alpha-beta-theta
alpha
```

Comment: Good point. Alternatively, `string[0...string.rindex('-')]`.

Comment: @7stud One of the question that always comes to my mind is what if the text="alpha-beta-1.0-SNAPSHOT.txt" ?

Comment: @Jason, Read Cary Swoveland's comment under your post.  Is there always a number after the part you want?  There has to be some pattern--if the file names are just random, then there is no way to get the part you want every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract just before last `-`, you can use this regex

```
(^.*)-(?:.*$)
```

[**Rubular Demo**](http://rubular.com/r/2qsM4tdr2Z)

For finding all non-overlapping matches, you can use `scan` as

```
str = "alpha-beta-1.0.txt"
print str.scan(/(^.*)-(?:.*$)/)[0][0]
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/Ly4ypm)**

You can also use `lookahead` as

```
.*(?=-)
```

Comment: Thanks @rock321987. Also, It seems I can apply @pascal's match expression as well:
`output1 = "alpha-beta-1.0.txt".match(/(^.*)-(?:.*$)/)[1]` Any reason to use scan vs match ?

Comment: @Jason You can use any of `scan` or `match`..`scan` returns all the match while `match` returns only the first match

Comment: Thanks a ton for your feedback.

Comment: @Jason Here is a good explanation :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291415/ruby-regex-scan-versus

Comment: KISS, `str.match(/.*(?=-)/)`

Comment: @Jason A good comparison here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993662/whats-the-difference-between-scan-and-match-on-ruby-string

Comment: @AvinashRaj your http://askubuntu.com/a/381560/329001 answer saved my `a**` yesterday

Comment: credit goes to the PPA owner :-).

Comment: I'd recommend `str[/\A.*(?=-)/m]`.

Answer (score 0):

With the information we have i'd propose:

```
output = "alpha-beta-1.0.txt".match(/(.*-.*)-.*/)[1]
```

`.*` matches a lot though. So perhaps you need a more restrictive match.